# Chrome browser flag control

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Could I able to change the flags that are available in the chrome  browser by using API ?? Can any one helps me to give a best solution for achieving the flag control.

Comment: Define "flag control". Add user-defined flags? Change value of flags at runtime?

Comment: yes, changing the flags status during run-time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to alter the behavior controlled by command-line switches using the Extensions/Apps APIs.

Comment: thanks for the info. By the way how I can achieve this ? do you know the possible way ?

Comment: Achieve what? What's your use case?

Comment: When a user try to see a page I need to enable one of the flag "Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia()".I thought one of the possible way would be by creating the extension and controlling it. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I think an extension can use screen capture regardless of that flag with `chrome.desktopCapture` API. It can then provide the stream to a tab. But it cannot enable an arbitrary website to access that. Again, what's your use case?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to achieve the screen sharing through WEBRTC.

Comment: On a website you control? Then you should write an extension that talks to it and provides the stream. See [chrome.desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) docs.